# HAProxy peering in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, kubernetes-statefulset

**Background**

Due to our application needs to use sticky tables for a custom header, we decided to use HAProxy, our layout looks as follows:

Nginx Ingress -> HAproxy service -> headless services of stateful application

So far stickiness works fine, but there is a scenario where if handled by the other HAproxy replica, it fails. We are trying to use peers to address this problem.

I use [bitnami helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/haproxy) to deploy it, this is my values file:

```
metadata:
  chartName: bitnami/haproxy
  chartVersion: 0.3.7
service:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: peers
      protocol: TCP
      port: 10000
      targetPort: 10000
containerPorts:
  - name: http
    containerPort: 8080
  - name: https
    containerPort: 8080
  - name: peers
    containerPort: 10000

configuration: |
  global
    log stdout format raw local0 debug

  defaults
    mode http
    option  httplog
    timeout client 10s
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout server 10s
    timeout http-request 10s
    log global

  resolvers default
    nameserver dns1 172.20.0.10:53
    hold timeout         30s
    hold refused         30s
    hold valid           10s

    resolve_retries 3
    timeout retry 3s

  peers hapeers  

    peer $(MY_POD_IP):10000  # I attempted to do something like this
    peer $(REPLICA_2_IP):10000 #

  frontend stats
    bind *:8404
    stats enable
    stats uri /
    stats refresh 10s

  frontend myfrontend
    mode http
    option httplog
    bind *:8080
    default_backend webservers

  backend webservers
    mode http
    log stdout local0 debug
    stick-table type string len 64 size 1m expire 1d peers hapeers
    stick on req.hdr(MyHeader)
    server s1 headless-service-1:8080 resolvers default check port 8080 inter 5s rise 2 fall 20
    server s2 headless-service-2:8080 resolvers default check port 8080 inter 5s rise 2 fall 20
    server s3 headless-service-3:8080 resolvers default check port 8080 inter 5s rise 2 fall 20

replicaCount: 2
extraEnvVars:
  - name: LOG_LEVEL
    value: debug
  - name: MY_POD_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
```

From what I read in HAProxy documentation, it requires the peers IP's, which in this case are the replicas IPs. However, the `configmap` does not allow injecting IPs from the HAProxy replicas.

I also thought of using a initContainer to modify the `haproxy.cfg` at deployment time with the correct IPs, but the volume is read-only and I would have to alter a fork of the chart to customize it.

If anyone has an idea of a different approach or workaround, I would appreciate the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`...the configmap does not allow injecting IPs from the HAProxy replicas.`

HAProxy's configuration supports [environment variables](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#2.3). Eg. peer $(MY_POD_IP):10000 => peer ${MY_POD_IP}:10000